# Yii2 : flash message displayed 2 times in my page

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have set a flash message for my application in the yii2 advanced template. The message also displayed on my particular page. But it displayed two times. I don't know how it will happen. Also, I have placed my code and image what I get.

In Controller File:

```
public function actionSign() {
    $model = new SignupForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', "User created successfully.");
         return $this->goHome();
    }
    return $this->render('signup', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

In Index File:

```
<?php if (Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('success')): ?>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
<button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
<h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>Saved!</h4>
<?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('success') ?>
</div>
```

The output shows like below:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vlgje.png)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: please add the complete action of the controller where you are setting hte flash message

Comment: It's possible that the flash message is rendered in your layout file. Try removing the flash render code from your index file and see if the first flash message is still displayed.

Comment: @Aslam, I have updated my controller action. Thanks

Comment: Like @Lisa says you have a Alert::widget() in your layout view

Comment: Lisa and @sfili_81, Thank you, guys. That is the problem I have commented that then its working fine. Thank you guys once again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('success')): ?>
    <!--<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
         <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
         <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>Saved!</h4>.
      </div>-->
 <?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('success') ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php if (Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('success')): ?>
   <?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('success') ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```